# Android create UI overlay element to display offline network status

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an overlay element that will pop up when the user loses connection, but also only want it to be on certain fragments.  Right now I'm including the offline overlay with my `nav_host.xml` and using my `ConnectionListener` to toggle it on and off in my `MainActivity` whenever connection is lost.

This works really well cause it pops up the moment connection is lost, but it overlay is in places where I don't need it, like settings or downloads.  The other problem is I want it to appear at different locations in different fragments.  Overlaying the header or tab layout does give good visibility that the system is offline, but I'd prefer it to appear below whatever header the fragment has.

[image]

Including the overlay in every fragment would make placement easier, but I can't think how best to toggle visibility using reusable code.  Although, if I'm using databinding then I could bind the visibility to the network status...

The overlay itself is just a layout with a `TextView` using a semi-transparent background color.

Is there a better way to setup this kind of UI element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `shared view model` where `ConnectionListener` exists in the `ViewModel` and any fragment or activity that wants to know about the connection status can grab the `ViewModel`. As for reacting to the connection events.

```
public class ShardViewModel extends ViewModel{
     private ConnectionListener connectionListener;
     private List<ConnectionListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();
     
     //call this once in main activity
     public void init(){
        connectionListener = new ConnectionListener {
           @Override
           public void closed(ConnectionEvent connectionEvent) {
               for(ConnectionListener listner : listners)
                    listener.closed(connectionEvent);
           }
           @Override
           public void disconnected(ConnectionEvent connectionEvent) {
               for(ConnectionListener listner : listners)
                    listener.disconnected(connectionEvent);
           }
           @Override
           public void opened(ConnectionEvent connectionEvent) {
               for(ConnectionListener listner : listners)
                    listener.opened(connectionEvent);
           }
        }
        //add the "real" listener whatever you are using to monitor connection.
     }
     //Fragments add their implementation of the ConnectionListener 
     //Meaning they can do whatever they want when they receive a message.
     public void addConnectionListener(ConnectionListener listener){
         if(listners!=null)
            listeners.add(listener);
     }
}
```